# @WebMvcTest does not find buildProperties

Tags: spring-mvc, junit

I have working JUnit tests for my MVC controllers. Now I wanted to display the build number in the footer of every page, so I added the following div in my thymeleaf templates:

```
<div class="versionInfo">Version <span th:text="${@buildProperties.getVersion()}"></span></div>
```

Now the test fail with:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'buildProperties' available

I tried to add it as a mock to no avail:

```
@MockBean
private BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

Or following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394808/3737177) (see my comment below the answer).

So how can I make my tests work again with the `BuildProperties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to access a bean via the following way: `${@buildProperties.getVersion()}` it's actually a SpEL expression for accessing a bean via a BeanReference. Unfortunately it has no default value and instead of returning `null` it throws an exception if the bean cannot be found.

I don't know any easy way to check if a bean exists in the context via SpEL.

So I think the best solution if you create a nested test configuration class and define a default BuildProperties bean there.

```
@TestConfiguration
public static class TestConfig {    
  @Bean 
  BuildProperties buildProperties() {
    return new BuildProperties(new Properties());
  }
}
```

Or you can create it as a separate class and use @Import(TestConfig.class) if you need this extra configuration in multiple test classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle , just add this to your build.grandle file:

```
SpringBoot { buildInfo() }
```

After configuring the spring-boot-maven-plugin you can build the application and access information about application’s build. 
The BuildProperties object is injected by Spring (@Autowired)

Comment: Thanks, but the basic logic is working if I call the page in a browser, but my problem is with the JUnit test of my MVC Tests.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the @WebMvcTest to a full blown @SpringBootTest would fix the problem, because then the ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration would be executed. As I wanted to stick to @WebMvcTest, I included the ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration to my WebMvcTest:

```
@WebMvcTest(YOUR_CONTROLLER_HERE.class)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.class)
class YOUR_CONTROLLER_HERETest{
    // Use at your will
    @Autowired
    private BuildProperties buildProperties;
}
```

Of course, this will only work, if the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin is correctly configured](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-build-info).