# Thymeleaf: Do not render during unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, thymeleaf

As I haven't gotten an answer for my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712564/webmvctest-does-not-find-buildproperties), I am looking for another approach. Is there a way to no not execute or include a fragment during unit testing?

I want to display the version and build number in the footer of my templates, thus I have the following line:

```
<div class="versionInfo">Version <span th:text="${@buildProperties.getVersion()}"></span></div>
```

This works well when running the application, but during unit test I get the exception:

> No bean named 'buildProperties' available

In the other question I am looking for a way to get this bean during unit test, as an alternative I am now looking for a way to exclude this template during unit tests. Something like this:

```
<div class="versionInfo" th:if="${!isUnitTest}">Version <span th:text="${@buildProperties.getVersion()}"></span></div>
```

I am using the following annotations on my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SimpleController.class)
```

Comment: Could you please share the java code. 1.Did you Autowire the class and is buildProperties available in context? 2. Did you use Mock or any ReflectionTestUtils ?
ReflectionTestUtils.setField("yourClass", buildProperties, objectBuildProperties)

Comment: The problem with buildProperties is, that it is an automatic thing from spring when it is built: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html

Comment: Do you use @SpringBootTest in the test class

Comment: @MebinJoe No, I am using `@WebMvcTest` as. I also tried it with `@SpringBootTest` but then `MockMvc` does not work as expected.

Comment: what is the exception you geting?

Comment: @MebinJoe Let's not discuss this problem in this ticket. Have a look at the other one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712564/webmvctest-does-not-find-buildproperties and see my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078044/webmvctest-fails-with-java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-load-applicati/53394808#53394808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a standard unit-test, use Mockito to mock the bean:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeTest{

  @Mock
  private BuildProperties buildProperties;

  ...
```

Or, if it's a Spring MVC test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest{

  @MockBean
  private BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

The version will be `null`, because all of the methods of the mocked bean returns `null`.

if you want to emulate a real version you can add something like this to your test or to the `setUp()` method

```
given(buildProperties.getVersion()).willReturn("whatever");
```

--------------- edit

Unfortunately all of the above solutions work only if the buildProperties bean was added to the model directly. 
But in your case you use the bean *directly* as a SpEL bean reference. Unfortunately I don't know any way to check if a bean exists in the context via SpEL.
Also, it's not a good practice to add extra code into your code for checking if it's running in test mode.
So I think the best solution if you create a nested test configuration class and define a default BuildProperties bean there.

```
@TestConfiguration
public static class TestConfig {    
  @Bean 
  BuildProperties buildProperties() {
    return new BuildProperties(new Properties());
  }
}
```

Or you can use `@Import(TestConfig.class)` if you need this extra configuration in multiple test classes.

Comment: I tried that but still get the same error mentioned in my OP.

Comment: Ok, your edit did the trick for me. For completeness sake, maybe add that you can use `@Import(TestConfig.class)` in your test classes so you don't need to inline it.

Comment: If you want some extra points, post your edited answer to my other question (you actually answered that one and not this one, but I have accepted it nonetheless): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712564/webmvctest-does-not-find-buildproperties

Answer (score 0):

I got a hint from a colleague that works for this question.

Just add an `application.properties` to `src/test/resources` with a custom property:

```
isUnitTest=true
```

Then I can simply check for this in my thymeleaf template:

```
<div class="versionInfo" th:if="${@environment.getProperty('isUnitTest') != 'true'}">Version <span th:text="${@buildProperties.getVersion()}"></span></div>
```

Though if someone finds a way to achieve this automatically with a thymeleaf setting or property I didn't find so far, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Adding extra code for testing if the code is running as a test is never a good idea. Check my edited answer

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but it is a workaround for now. I'll check your other suggestion.